# Importing Content with SDL Web Content Porter 8.5 fails

Tags: content-manager, content-porter-web8

When importing content with SDL Content Porter 8.5 into an SDL Web 8.5 instance it fails with the following error:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 
‘Anonymous’. The authentication header received from the server was 
‘Negotiate,NTLM’.
```

Important to know is that it fails in the last step. The authentication itself, connecting to the content manager works. It only fails when performing the actual import (last step)

Comment: Are you using SSO?

Comment: No, they are using NTLM. The setup is out-of-the box.

Comment: Have you or do you plan to set up Authentication with Active Directory and LDAP? I was seeing a very similar issue when running a DXA upgrade script (which also uses the import/export service). Completing the steps to set up Authentication with Active Directory and LDAP allowed me to run my script using the 'Basic' authentication option. You could also try comparing your authentication settings in IIS to another environment where a similar import works.